# How to show different layouts in one activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I have a activity in that I need to change the layout.

In the first layout I have four buttons to display and in the second I need a `GridView` to display images.

I need to show the second layout in an `AsyncTask onPostExecute` method.

For now, I'm trying to set two setContentViews, but I get the following exception: `ClassCastException`

> ```
>     @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_focusarea);
>                                 videoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         public void onClick(View arg0) {
>             new LoadFiles().execute();
>         }
>     });
>     animateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         public void onClick(View arg0) {
>             new LoadFiles().execute();          
>         }
>     });
>     pdfBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         public void onClick(View arg0) {
>             new LoadPDFFiles().execute();           
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

And in my postExecute i try like this

> ```
>   protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
>       pDialog.dismiss();    
>       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>     public void run() {
>         setContentView(R.layout.gallery); 
>             girGridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1_bir);
>             girGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));     
>                 girGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
>         @Override
>              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long arg3) {
>     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), GridViewConfig.getResim_list().get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
>     }
> });
>                 }
>     });
> ```

Comment: Please post your logcat errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of that you can have a layout that contains both a wrapper for your four buttons and  other for the GridView while this last one is with visibility set to 'gone'.

When the AsycTask finished, you hide the buttons layout and show the GridView layout.

Comment: @OneManArmy it's simple. in your xml you put a wrapper layout (like linearlayout, relativelayout) around all your buttons and also another wrapper layout around your gridview) -- this last one has visibility:gone. Also, you need the findviewbyid of your two wrappers layouts and when the asynctaskfinished you put wrapper1.setvisibility(view.gone) and wrapper2.setvisibility(view.visible)

Comment: plz can you post some code for xml..plz give example..help me

Comment: @dwbrito Please share a tutorial with us !!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using two layouts use a single layout as bellow

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/MyLayoutOne"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Hi This is my first layout" />


     <!-- Your first layout contents add here-->



</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/MyLayoutTwo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Hi This is my Second layout" />


    <!-- Your second layout contents add here -->


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Add your first layout contents inside MyLayoutOne and second layout contents inside MyLayoutTwo

And use following codes inside your activity,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


LinearLayout MyLayoutOne;
LinearLayout MyLayoutTwo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyLayoutOne=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.MyLayoutOne);
    MyLayoutTwo=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.MyLayoutTwo);


    // this will make first layout visible
    MyLayoutOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    // this will make second layout hidden from your layout
    MyLayoutTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    //=========================================

    //in your post create add this codes 

    //=========================================

    // this will make first layout hidden
    MyLayoutOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // this will make second layout visible in your layout
    MyLayoutTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //=========================================


}



}
```

This is a simplest method you must study fragments for better UI management. You can use viewflipper also.

So Study Fragments and Viewflipper..

Comment: change id of main LinearLayout to the child LinearLayout.. and initialize layouts outside onCreate... I have posted the code below..

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set one content view with two layouts or two fragments? A layout can be like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/text1">          
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/text2">          
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/text3">          
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/text4">          
    </Button>
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ...
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how to set two layouts??i don't know to do that..Im new to android..Please help me to set that..

Comment: There can only be one parent layout, but it can contain as many child layouts as you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use one setContentView() and define separates Linear/Relative layout one for buttons and second for gridView.And hide/show the Views according to your need.
```

Comment: Using setVisbility(View.GONE) and setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) to your views that you find from xml layout file.a

Answer (score 0):

onPostExecute of AsyncTask runs on UI thread so you need not specify runonUiThread explicitly.Instead of using 2 setcontent View it is better to have 2 views in your layout file and make it visible invisible as required.

Answer (score 0):

Friend change the id of wrapper1 to child as below,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Focusarea" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1_bir"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vid_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and initialize your linear layouts outside oncreate as below,

```
LinearLayout wrapper1;
RelativeLayout wrapper2;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    wrapper1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.wrapper1);
    wrapper2=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.wrapper2);


    // this will make first layout visible
    wrapper2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    // this will make second layout hidden from your layout
    wrapper1.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    ImageView videoBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vid_btn);
    ImageView animateBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.anit_btn);
    ImageView pdfBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pdf_btn);

    videoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                new LoadFiles().execute();                         
            }
    });
    animateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    new LoadFiles().execute();                     
            }
    });
    pdfBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    new LoadPDFFiles().execute();                  
            }
    });
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting VIDEOS
            pDialog.dismiss();     
            vid=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(vid));
            videoUrl=parsing.parse(videoUrl);
            System.out.println("VIDEO URL" +videoUrl);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {


                            //--here you wont need to initialize again--

                                // this will make first layout visible
                                wrapper1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                // this will make second layout hidden from your layout
                                wrapper2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            girGridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1_bir);
                            //ListView gibi buna da adapter set ediliyor.
                            girGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));                            
                            girGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long arg3) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), GridViewConfig.getResim_list().get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                              
                                            }
                                    });
                            }
        });
```